# Query not workin

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query,

```
SELECT DISTINCT username, publishedapp
FROM tbl_name
WHERE username in
(
  SELECT username
  FROM tbl_name
  WHERE publishedapp = \"Mencap@Work2-1\"
)
  AND publishedapp  NOT LIKE \"%Desktop%\"
  AND publishedapp  NOT LIKE \"%RDP%\"
GROUP BY username
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT publishedapp) > 1
```

which works perfectly on a db,table but not in another, the DBs have the same type of content just the one which doesn't work on has more row as it has been gathering information for longer time.

on the newer table im getting 0 as result to the query, the table definitely has content as I've seen the rows and columns on PHPMyadmin and also have user run this query

```
SELECT username, publishedapp
FROM tbl_name
ORDER BY username
```

The original table
[image]

The new table
[image]

Im specting something like this coming out
[image]

Any ideas what could this be?

Comment: Probably because none of the rows in the new DB match the query. You can't be helped unless you at least show us some rows that you expect to be outputted

Comment: im quite sure there are rows that match the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you do to troubleshoot something like this is to break down the query into pieces until you find the source of the problem. Sometimes you may need to use select * or specify columns in the join or the where clause that you are not returning in the final product to see what is going on. I would do something like the following, running each one until you see where the records fall out.:

```
  SELECT username
  FROM tbl_name
  WHERE publishedapp = \"Mencap@Work2-1\"

 SELECT *
FROM tbl_name
WHERE username in
(
  SELECT username
  FROM tbl_name
  WHERE publishedapp = \"Mencap@Work2-1\"
)
 AND publishedapp  NOT LIKE \"%Desktop%\"

 SELECT *
FROM tbl_name
WHERE username in
(
  SELECT username
  FROM tbl_name
  WHERE publishedapp = \"Mencap@Work2-1\"
)
 AND publishedapp  NOT LIKE \"%Desktop%\" 
 AND publishedapp  NOT LIKE \"%RDP%\" 

 SELECT username, publishedapp, COUNT(DISTINCT publishedapp) 
FROM tbl_name
WHERE username in
(
  SELECT username
  FROM tbl_name
  WHERE publishedapp = \"Mencap@Work2-1\"
)
 AND publishedapp  NOT LIKE \"%Desktop%\" 
 AND publishedapp  NOT LIKE \"%RDP%\"  
GROUP BY username,publishedapp
```

Note that I correctly used group by. You should never under any circumstances use group by the way you did, your results can be incorrect. You should use group by the way it was intended to work and the way every other database works by including all columns in the select that are not part of the aggregate.

Answer (score 0):

Try simplifying the query.  If I understand correctly:

```
SELECT username, group_concat(publishedapp)
FROM tbl_name
WHERE publishedapp NOT LIKE '%Desktop%' AND
      publishedapp NOT LIKE '%RDP%'
GROUP BY username
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT publishedapp) > 1 AND
       SUM(publishedapp = 'Mencap@Work2-1') > 0;
```

There is also the possibility that although names *look* similar they are not.  For instance, there could be trailing spaces at the end of an app name.  Does this return what you expect?

```
select *
from tbl_name
where publishedapp = 'Mencap@Work2-1'
```

Comment: Im tried something similar, but tried this too and I get back the same thing...
even tried with `'%Mencap@Work2-1%'` but no look, also im working with php so the query is more like this `$sql = "select *
from tbl_name
where publishedapp = '%Mencap@Work2-1%'";` I hope the quote are not messing the things up...

Comment: You want to try the query in your comment with `like` and not `=`.

Comment: Is it possible to set up a SQL Fiddle?

Answer (score -1):

**Maybe none of the rows in the seconds Database got `publishedapp > 1` ??** 
CHECK IT!

*Do you get any Errors in DB Logs?
Check the table/column names in the second DB for typos.
Show us your Tables, without that we can't help you in any way.*

Comment: Im sure there is no typos and quite sure that the query should return something.